# javascript reference the nested document in a mongoose array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema which has an array I want to reference a document
that is nested inside that array from another schema. How can I go about it.

This is my schema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    first_name      : String,
    last_name       : String,
    exam_test_id    :{
        type            : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref             : 'departmentSchema.members'
    }
});

var departmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name                : String,
    description         : String,
    members             :[{
        commencement_date   : Date, 
        post                : String,
        function            : String
    }]
})
```

I am confused whether that ref is appropriate, if it is not right is there another 
way I can go about it while still have a nested sub document

Comment: Why `'department.members'` ? `department` doesn't match anything. Try with `'departmentSchema.members'` ?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. It has been corrected. would it work?